# Removing virtual C: created by wine

Tags: wine

After removing wine, how would I remove virtual `C:\` created by wine in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is there any problem if I remove it?

Comment: Just remove the whole `.wine` folder. It contains the emulated file system inside. No problem with that.

Comment: From the terminal type `rm -rf ~/.wine` but keep in mind that a wine profile could have been created in any folder depending on the context; for example if you used PlayOnLinux then the folder will be under `~/.PlayOnLinux`.

Answer (score 6):

The `.wine` folder is where everything "wine" is stored including settings and the emulated file system, the "virtual C." as you called it.

If you already deleted Wine then you can and should remove the whole `.wine` folder (unless you want to reinstall Wine later and keep the old settings and installed software).

No problems should occur by removing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is folder called `.wine` in your home folder. You can see it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while viewing your home folder in the file browser.

Delete the folder `.wine`. This will erase all your wine files.

But **there's one problem**: You will lose all the files and programs created by Wine. That's all. You may lose progress of some games, depending on where the game saves the progress.